# Kendo UI Mobile - "data-click" attribute ignored on anchor tag in listview

Tags: html, listview, kendo-ui

I have a situation like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a data-click="resolveAddressPrefix" href="<address-suffix>" data-rel="external">
            <span>Here is some stuff inside my anchor tag</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Kendo's data-* attributes are ignored. If I change `data-click` to `onclick`, the function executes, but this is not a solution.

I tried adding a `data-role="button"` to my anchor tag, but it didn't do anything at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using the latest service pack release of Kendo UI Mobile and JQuery.

PS: I would really like to solve this without initializing via javascript or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Further research finally led me to a forum post in the Kendo Mobile forums that I hadn't seen. Basically, this is a bug and is fixed in the latest internal build. However, as a workaround for my situation at the moment, I applied the `data-click="resolveAddressPrefix"` attribute to the `<ul>` tag instead. Then, in my `resolveAddressPrefix` function I added `event.preventDefault()`. Finally, since this bug is also tied with `data-rel="external"`, I used javascript to manually perform an "external"   link, `window.location.href = ...` Hopefully this helps somebody who doesn't have access to internal builds.

Comment: I still have this problem, do you know if/when it's supposed to be fixed?

Comment: @Dean I am using Kendo UI Complete v2013.1.319 and so far it looks like it's been fixed.